# Kafka Streams: does StateStore contains all data or only some partitioned data when get from context?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a kafka topic with several partitions and a kafka streams application that reads the topic.

The kafka streams application contains a Transaformer that store data into a local RockDB persistent StateStore DB. The Transformer is instantiated automatically by the framework via a TransformerSupplier

```
TransformerSupplier<String, Message, KeyValue<String, Message>> getTransformerSupplier(){
            if(transformerSupplier == null)
                transformerSupplier = () -> new MyTransformer();
            return transformerSupplier;
    }
```

In addition, the transformer schedules a punctuator that needs to perform operations to the same StateStore.

My question is: *when the punctuator reads the StateStore, all elements of all partitions are read or the StateStore received by the context is limited to the partitions read by the transformer?*

Here is an example of my Transformer:

```
public class MyTransformer implements Transformer<String, Message, KeyValue<String, Message>> {
        private KeyValueStore<String, Message> stateStore;
        private ProcessorContext context;
        private MyScheduler myScheduler;
    
        @Override
        public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
            this.context = context;
            stateStore = this.context.getStateStore(myStateStoreName);
            myScheduler.initAndSchedule(this.context);
        }
@Override
    public KeyValue<String, Message> transform(String key, Message newValue) {
        stateStore.put(key, newValue);
        return null;
    }
```

and this is the content of my punctuator

```
public void initAndSchedule(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        stateStore = this.context.getStateStore(myStateStoreName);
        this.context.schedule(Duration.ofSeconds(schedulerSeconds), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, this);
    }

 @Override
    public void punctuate(long timestamp) {
        stateStore.all().forEachRemaining(keyValue -> {
            logger.info("      StateStore key {}", keyValue.key);
        });
    }
```

As per above the StateStore is given by the context of the Transformer but 'stateStore.all().forEachRemaining()' function is allowing me to scan all data received by the topic or only the partitions ready by the transformer which provides the context?

Practical scenarion:
KafkaTopic contains 10 partitions -> we have 2 pods each of them reads 5 partitions -> transformerSupplier of each pod creates 3 instances of MyTransformer, each of them reading 2 or 1 partitions, therefore each LocalStore will contain data of 5 partitions -> each transformer instantiate a scheduler, therefore there are 3 Schedulers instances per each pod reading the LocalStores.
*Do they have access to the whole 5 partitions or only the 2 or 1 partition handled by the transformer?*

thanks

Comment: I believe it's only the local store. You need to use RPC to get data from all instances of the same application  - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

Comment: Hi, the instance into the link you posted is for example a pod into k9s and this is expected for me. The question is related to what I am reading from my local StateStore DB, if it is data of all partitions the instance is reading or only some of the partitions read by the single transformer instance. 
This is because the TransformesSupplier if each pod generates multiple instances of the Transformer assigned to certain Kafka topic partition.
Scenario below:

Comment: KafkaTopic contains 10 partitions -> we have 2 pods each of them reads 5 partitions -> transformerSupplier of each pod creates 3 instances of MyTransformer, each of them reading 2 or 1 partitions, therefore each LocalStore will contain data of 5 partitions -> each transformer instantiate a scheduler, therefore there are 3 Schedulers instances per each pod reading the LocalStores. Do they have access to the whole 5 partitions or only the 2 or 1 partition handled by the transformer?

Comment: Like I said, the Transformer isn't what matters. Each individual deployment of the application only has data stored for its assigned partitions, based on the consumer group. The KafkaStreams Topology controls the store access, rather than the number of Transform instances

Comment: yes, I am using a StateStore not a GlobalStateStore, therefore each deployment see part of the topic. The problem is that even within the single deployment the StateStore provided is showing only part of the local store. That is why the framwork is designet to produce multiple punctuators per deployment..

Answer (score 2):

I have added some loggings and indeed the StateStore provided by

```
this.context.getStateStore(myStateStoreName);
```

to the punctuator contains only the data coming from the partition read by the myTransformer.
Therefore all instances of the punctuator are needed to read all data